# Facebook login not working :ERROR: Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Ok So I made an app with Facebook login now I filled everything out that they asked me and all of my code should be working fine but I am getting this notification when I try to login with the Facebook login button

> Facebook login is currently unavailable for this app since we are updating additional detail for this app

I am not sure is this a code problem or a Facebook problem or did I miss something when I filled out all the details they asked, I need help

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-check app mode on the Developer account is live or not.
[image]

If the off switch to live.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the facebook developers console for your app, go to App Review-> Permissions and Features. Set the public_profile and email to have advanced access. This will allow all facebook users to have access and these two settings are auto granted. Ensure the Access Level indicates Advanced Access.

Facebook Login of iOS app is working well without Advanced Access setting.